# Syntax error in MariaDB Stored Procedure With Parameter

Tags: mariadb

Im trying to create a procedure for a railway database on phpmyadmin. In which the train number, train date, and category is read from the passenger. On the basis of the values provided by the passenger, corresponding record is retrieved from the Train_Status table. If the desired category is AC, then total number of AC seats and number of booked AC seats are compared in order to find whether ticket can be booked or not. Similarly, it can be checked for the general category. If ticket can be booked, then passenger details are read and stored in the Passenger table.

I have scratched my head on the procdure syntax but it is still giving an error. Tried changing syntax, removing the check condtion from variables but nothing seems to work.

The error it gives is

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'CHECK (train_number>=1 AND train_number<=5);   DECLARE t_date
> DATE;   DECLA...' at line 6"

The mariadb version is 10.4.25

Here it is what I created

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE Booking (t_num int(1), t_date DATE, category varchar(10) )

BEGIN


  DECLARE t_num int(1) CHECK (train_number>=1 AND train_number<=5);
  DECLARE t_date DATE;
  DECLARE category ENUM('AC', 'General');
  DECLARE status ENUM('Confirmed', 'Waiting');

  DECLARE getTrain CURSOR FOR
  SELECT * FROM Train_Status
  WHERE train_number = t_num AND train_date = t_date;
  DECLARE trec Train_Status % ROWTYPE;



DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('READING VALUES');
t_num := &t_num;
t_date := '&t_date';
category := '&category';

OPEN getTrain;
LOOP 
FETCH FROM getTrain INTO trec;
EXIT WHEN getTrain % NOTFOUND;
IF(category = 'AC') THEN

 IF(trec.t_acseats - trec.b_acseats) > 0 THEN
  status := 'Confirmed';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Seat Confirmed');
ELSIF(trec.t_acseats - trec.b_acseats) > -2 THEN 
status := 'Waiting';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Seat Waiting');
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Seat Not Available');
EXIT;
END IF;
IF status = 'Confirmed' OR status = 'Waiting' THEN
UPDATE Train_Status SET b_acseats = b_acseats + 1 WHERE
  TrainNumber = t_num and TrainDate = t_date;
END IF;

ELSIF(category = 'General') THEN
 IF(trec.t_genseats - trec.b_genseats) > 0 THEN
  status := 'Confirmed';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Seat Confirmed');

ELSIF(trec.t_genseats - trec.b_genseats) > -2 THEN
 status := 'Waiting';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Seat Waiting');
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Seat Not Available');
EXIT;
END IF;
IF status = 'Confirmed' OR status = 'Waiting' THEN
UPDATE Train_Status SET b_genseats = b_genseats + 1 
WHERE TrainNumber = t_num and TrainDate = t_date;
END IF;

ELSE 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Category');
END IF;
IF status = 'Confirmed' OR status = 'Waiting' THEN
INSERT INTO Passengers
VALUES ('&T_ID', t_num, t_date, '&Name', &Age, '&Sex', '&Address', status, category);
END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE getTrain;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: It says "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHECK (train_number>=1 AND train_number<=5);
  DECLARE t_date DATE;
  DECLA...' at line 6"

Comment: Check is not possible there

Comment: You have copy-pasted an oracle stored procedure in mariadb. Languages used by stored procedures greatly differ between RDBMS products. A stored procedure from one is extremely unlikely to run in another without modification. This stored procedure must be completely rewritten for mariadb as there are tons of syntax / feature used there which are not supported by mariadb.

Comment: I tried without check too, didn't work @Jens

Comment: didn't work mean?

Comment: It gave the same error

Comment: Is there any proper guide for the MariaDB syntax? Their website doesn't seem to have good documentation for the procedures at least. @Shadow

Comment: @AhsanAhmed their website is the best documentation I have seen for MariaDB. You should note that MariaDB's stored procedure language is a lot less developed, therefore a lot less complicated than Oracle's. It is possible that what you perceive as lack of documentation is just lack of features. For example, the documentation on the declare statement syntax on their website clearly show that it does not support the check option...

Comment: Yeah, maybe you are right. I'm making some progress in it. Hopefully will be able to make it error-free. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Feel free to [request](https://jira.mariadb.org) and/or [write](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/contributing-code/) the feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Check can't be used while declaring the variables. Only name and data type should be there.

> 2. Check cursor syntax from MariaDB documentation.

These two things will solve your 70% problems. Rest you can figure out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).